# Django - processing model data before saving

Tags: python, django

I have a django model. I need to get `username` and `password`. But at that time I want to process them by `vk()` class to get `uid`, `token`, `secret` and save model with fields from `vk()` class only. How can I do it?

```
from django.db import models
from vk_class import vk

class data(models.Model):

    # that's what I ask for
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # that's only what I want to save
    uid = vk(username=username, password=password).uid
    token = vk(username=username, password=password).token
    secret = vk(username=username, password=password).secret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update after comments**
You could use `editable=False` for this fields and custom manager to overload `objects.create` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models

class DataQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def create(self, username, password, *args, **kwargs):
        vk_data = vk(username=username, password=password)
        kwargs.update({
            'uid': vk_data.uid,
            'token': vk_data.token,
            'secret': vk_data.secret
        })
        return self.create(*args, **kwargs)

class data(models.Model):
    # that's only what I want to save
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, editable=False)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, editable=False)
    secret = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, editable=False)

    objects = DataQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Then in code

```
data_obj = data.objects.create(username, password)
```

Comment: What type does `instance.username` return?
And how can I prevent writing `username` and `password` in database and use `uid` as django's `id`?

Comment: @sardorbek Why does one want to duplicate username and password fields as Django Auth already does it for you!

Comment: @abijith-mg Why I need to store user credentials when I can get termless token to get access VK API and use it?

Comment: @AbijithMg First of all there is no `Auth` model in django, maybe you meant `User`, but OP didn't provide any info on how this is related to default `User` model. That is why I didn't suggest anything like this.

Comment: @ВячеславКозловский You accepted answer, do you still need your question's in comments answered?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Yes, except the first one

Comment: @vkozlovsk read updated answer. Regarting uid as pk this is separte question read this as a hint https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield